# Starting Activities from List in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app and I have run into a problem.
The first activity has a list with many options, each list object consists of a picture and some text. The goal is a user picks a list option and it opens a new activity.
I have a Array List with instances of a class that contains the image, text, and name of activity that needs to start. When I call StartActivity in my onListItemClick(), how can I get the activity name in the new Intent and make it accept the name? Is this possible or is this a terrible way of going at what I want?
I am very new to android and am sorry for any confusion.
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make your custom list class that contains the image, text, and name of the activity also have another field that is an instance of a Class object of the Activity you want to start?  That way, you can just use that to start the new Activity.

Comment: I like this but have a few questions on it. First how would I hook it up to the click listener? and second, would I even need the field with the name of the activity if I already have an instance of it?

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(this, yourCustomObject.getActivityClass());

Comment: If the field with the name is used purely for getting your new Activity running, then I would say that you can get rid of it, but if the name is being rendered somewhere in the List, then you may want to keep it.  It is really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which might be easier than creating a custom class...create a Hashmap which contains the ListView Object and the Activity you want to start.

```
public static final HashMap<Object, Class> map = new HashMap<Object, Class>();
    static {
        map.put(key0, Activity0.class);
        map.put(key1, Activity1.class);
        map.put(key2, Activity2.class);
    }


@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, map.get(lv.getItemAtPosition(position));

    }
```

Obviously the the Object in the HashMap definition will need to be changed to the Object which you're keying off of.